# Angular2 conditional switchMap and patchValue

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a component to create or edit Trips and I want to use the same form . How do can I check in advance if there are any parameters?

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.trip = this.fb.group({
      id: '',
      name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]],
    });

    this.route.paramMap
    .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => this.tripService.getTrip(+params.get('id')))
    .subscribe((trip: any) => {
        this.trip.patchValue({
          id: trip.id,
          name: trip.name
        });
    })
}
```

I already tried something like this but without success

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.trip = this.fb.group({
      id: '',
      name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]],
    });

    this.route.paramMap
    .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
         console.log(params.get('id'))
      if(params.get('id')){

          this.tripService.getTrip(params.get('id')).subscribe((trip: any) => {
              this.trip.patchValue({
                id: trip.id,
                name: trip.name
              });
          })
        }

    }

    )

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something similar to this:

```
this.route.paramMap
.filter(params => params.get('id') !== undefined)
.switchMap((params: ParamMap) => this.tripService.getTrip(+params.get('id')))
.subscribe((trip: any) => {
    this.trip.patchValue({
      id: trip.id,
      name: trip.name
    });
})
```

}

Comment: Now I'm getting this error: "ERROR TypeError: this.route.paramMap.filter is not a function"

Comment: You need to include the rxjs import for that function in your import statements

Comment: Thanks a lot, with the import of 'rxjs/add/operator/filter' it worked. I only needed to change the validation from "undefined" to "null" .

Comment: I have another question, it is necessary to write params.get('id') multiple times, or is there a way to put that value on a var and access it on filter and switchMap ?

Comment: In my opinion, it's a very inexpensive call and is easy to understand the intent how it is currently

Comment: Thanks a lot! Best Regards.